# How to convert a spark dataframe to a matrix with indices?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, matrix, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe df looking like this:

```
C1toC1 C1toC2 C1toC3 C2toC1 C2toC2 C2toC3 C3toC1 C3toC2 C3toC3
2      0      6      7      32     3      3      0      10
2      10     23     6      32     4      3      10     34
3      10     23     6      35     12     6      76     34
2      13     25     2      41     4      4      10     32
```

How do I convert this to 4 matrices looking like this:

```
   C1 C2 C3       C1 C2 C3      C1 C2 C3       C1 C2 C3
C1 2  0  6     C1 2  10 23   C1 3  10 23    C1 2  13 25
C2 7  32 3     C2 6  32 4    C2 6  35 12    C2 2  41 4 
C3 3  0  10 ,  C3 3  10 34,  C3 6  76 34 ,  C3 4  10 32
```

which is could then write to a csv file?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use 'collect' to get the rows into a list and for matrix for each element in this list, you can just slice for every 3 objects  of this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about how you want the CSV output to look like, but this will bring you one step closer to what you wanted. I suppose each id will correspond to a csv file, but I'll wait for you to confirm.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'id',
    F.monotonically_increasing_id()
).select(
    'id',
    F.posexplode_outer(
        F.array(
            F.array(df.columns[:3]),
            F.array(df.columns[3:6]),
            F.array(df.columns[6:])
       )
    )
).selectExpr(
    'id',
    "concat('C', pos+1) name",
    'col[0] C1',
    'col[1] C2',
    'col[2] C3')

df2.show()
+---+----+---+---+---+
| id|name| C1| C2| C3|
+---+----+---+---+---+
|  0|  C1|  2|  0|  6|
|  0|  C2|  7| 32|  3|
|  0|  C3|  3|  0| 10|
|  1|  C1|  2| 10| 23|
|  1|  C2|  6| 32|  4|
|  1|  C3|  3| 10| 34|
|  2|  C1|  3| 10| 23|
|  2|  C2|  6| 35| 12|
|  2|  C3|  6| 76| 34|
|  3|  C1|  2| 13| 25|
|  3|  C2|  2| 41|  4|
|  3|  C3|  4| 10| 32|
+---+----+---+---+---+
```